# Check Radio-Button option failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatable, radio-button

I load some html data (radio-buttons, button) in jQuery Datatable. Then, when i want to get the checked option, i always get the first option.

CODE:

```
$('#image_table').dataTable().fnAddData
(
        [
            '<div id="rb1" class="rdio rdio-default">' +
                '<input type="radio" name="rotateMode" id="radioDefault1" value="1" checked="checked" />' +
                '<label for="radioDefault">Paisaje</label>' +
            '</div>' + 
            '<div id="rb2" class="rdio rdio-default">' +
                '<input type="radio" name="rotateMode" id="radioDefault2" value="2" />' +
                '<label for="radioDefault2">Retrato</label>' +
            '</div>',
            '<button onClick="allowImage(this)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>'
        ]
)


allowImage = function(a) {
    var index = $(a).parent().parent().index();
    var row = $('#image_table').dataTable().fnGetData(index);
    var opt = $(row[0]).find('input[name=rotateMode]:radio:checked').val();

    alert(opt);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mdqbpkg/)

Anyone know if I'm doing wrong or it's Jquery Datatable bug. Thanks in advance. Sorry for my spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
allowImage = function(a) {
    alert($(a).closest("td").prev('td').find("input[name='rotateMode']:checked").val())
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mdqbpkg/3/)

Comment: Sorry I don't have much knowledge in `dataTable`. It seems `fnGetData` returns data for given row, not the DOM. I did it with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I had not thought to try directly with jQuery selectors.